# Converting shapefiles from S3 to GeoJSON in JavaScript for web map

Tags: shapefile, openlayers, javascript, geojson, amazon-web-services

I am working on a web map using OpenLayers and have encountered a challenge in converting shapefiles stored in an S3 bucket to GeoJSON using JavaScript. My goal is to display the converted shapefiles to a GeoJSON in the web browser environment. I can retrieve the shapefiles from my bucket using "https://example.shp","https://example.dbf" etc..

I've tried a few things but haven't had any luck. The code below requires promise or require to be defined in my web app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Display Shapefile on Map</title>
  <style>
    body, html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.6.5/ol.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/shpjs"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/shapefile/dist/shapefile.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/shpjs@latest/dist/shp.js"></script>


  <script>
    var basemapSource = new ol.source.OSM();
    var basemapLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: basemapSource
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [basemapLayer],
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-107.642, 42.321]),
        zoom: 6
      })
    });

    shp("https://example.shp").then(function(geojson) {
        // Handle the converted GeoJSON data
        console.log(geojson);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
      
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried https://github.com/wavded/js-shapefile-to-geojson but would get `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker':`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>js-shapefile-to-geojson Demo Page</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
            #map {
                height: 400px;
                background-color: #eee;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
         <a href="http://github.com/wavded/js-shapefile-to-geojson"><img style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0;" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_right_darkblue_121621.png" alt="Fork me on GitHub" /></a>
        <h2>js-shapefile-to-geojson Demo Page</h2>
        <p>Pure client-side JavaScript (no server side code) parsing of shapefiles and dbase files to GeoJSON format displayed using OpenLayers.</p>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script src="http://rs1.adc4gis.com/js/openlayers/2.9.1/OpenLayers-Proj4.js"></script>
        <script src="stream.js"></script>
        <script src="shapefile.js"></script>
        <script src="dbf.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            OpenLayers._getScriptLocation = function(){
                return "http://rs1.adc4gis.com/js/openlayers/2.9.1/";
            };


            var starttime = +new Date,
                map = new OpenLayers.Map("map",{allOverlays: true}),
                parser = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(),
                vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Converted"),

                shapefile = new Shapefile({
                    shp: "https://example.shp",
                }, function(data){
                    var features = parser.read(data.geojson);
                    vector.addFeatures(features);
                    map.zoomToExtent(vector.getDataExtent());

                    console.log("took",new Date - starttime,"milliseconds")
                    console.log(data);
                })

            map.addLayer(vector);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I convert my shapefile stored on an S3 bucket to a GeoJSON using JavaScript?

Comment: "Best" Questions are intrinsically *opinion-based*, so you might have trouble keeping this Question open if you don't [Edit] it to be less subjective (the [Help Center](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) has suggestions).

Comment: A number of web mapping solutions exist to solve this problem, choosing between them is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way to convert Shapefiles to GeoJSOM is [Shapefile.js](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js) library from Calvin Metcalf. All you need is to include https://unpkg.com/shpjs@latest/dist/shp.js and then call `shp` function to convert Shapefile to GeoJSON.

In the code below Shapefile https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/gadm/gadm4.1/shp/gadm41_SVN_shp.zip is loaded from local server (couldn't do it from the source beacuse of CORS) and then displayed on OpenLayers map:

```
const tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM(),
});

const source = new ol.source.Vector();
const vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: source,
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [tileLayer, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([15, 46]),
    zoom: 8
  }),
});

var base = 'http://localhost/OpenLayersExamples/data/gadm41_SVN_shp.zip';
shp(base).then(function(data){
  data.forEach(function(geoJSON) {        
    var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geoJSON, {
      dataProjection:'EPSG:4326',
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
    });
    source.addFeatures(features);
  });
});
```

**Note**: URL parameter in `shp` call must be full URL, not relative path to your server.

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious or "clean" option is to convert the data (using GIS tools or otherwise) into one of the web-friendly formats that can be readily consumed by OpenLayers (hint: shapefile is *not* one of them) and serve it from S3.

**For converting GeoJSON to SHP:**

A) A simpler flow using `shp-write` package is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325664/converting-geojson-to-shapefile-in-javascript-using-shp-write). While this approach works on client-side which is probably close to what you wanted originally, there are two drawbacks: 1) the official `shp-write` is no longer actively maintained, I had to rely on one of the forks to verify it is working (https://jsfiddle.net/bnos76zk/) 2) as the shapefile generation relies on client browser, you cannot guarantee it will work for every user, and the mechanism may be broken in some future browser update. So it is probably safer to serve all the content on S3 without going through this.

B) A more advanced flow would be to leverage S3 events to perform data conversion as and when data is uploaded to the bucket. [This](https://sysadmins.co.za/convert-csv-to-json-files-with-aws-lambda-and-s3-events/) is an example for csv2json but the same idea can be applied to any data formats.

Comment: Thanks @prusswan. I was thinking that might be the easiest solution. My users will want to download the data as a shapefile which is why I was going to store it as a shapefile in S3. Do you know if it's possible to export a GeoJSON to a shapefile through a web app in Javascript?

Comment: @JNN yes, but if you are using S3 you might as well take advantage of AWS services to take care of the data conversion (for more flexibility you could even serve the S3 data out as APIs with as many data formats that you want to support)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using AWS. My organization has its own service that uses the Simple Storage Service (S3) protocol that I'm using to store my data.